# Is there a way to create a Rails resource route called `index`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I want to add a resource route called `index` to a Rails 4 application but the generated routes aren't as expected. However, if I use another name (such as `show_index`), they are. To demonstrate, I'll begin with a vanilla Rails app that has no routes:

```
$ rake routes
You don't have any routes defined!
```

I add the below into `config/routes.rb`:

```
  resources :items
```

Which produces the following resourceful Rails routes:

```
   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
    items GET    /items(.:format)          items#index
          POST   /items(.:format)          items#create
 new_item GET    /items/new(.:format)      items#new
edit_item GET    /items/:id/edit(.:format) items#edit
     item GET    /items/:id(.:format)      items#show
          PATCH  /items/:id(.:format)      items#update
          PUT    /items/:id(.:format)      items#update
          DELETE /items/:id(.:format)      items#destroy
```

The application has a `show` action that can render a so-called `index` if the parameter hash contains `{with: 'index'}` (this *index* is an application-specific thing, rather than a *collection* of items or anything like that).

I add a custom `index` route to invoke the `show` action with the additional parameter:

```
  resources :items do
    get 'index' => 'items#show', with: 'index'
  end
```

This produces a new route but it has `item_id` instead of the expected `id` (compare with `edit_item` in the list above):

```
item_index GET    /items/:item_id/index(.:format) items#show {:with=>"index"}
```

The [Routing documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) [explains](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) that the way to get `:id` is to use `on: :member`, so the route would need to be

```
get 'index' => 'items#show', with: 'index', on: :member
```

but that doesn't produce the expected results. It adds the expected route but it steals the `item` method prefix from the default `show` action instead of using its own `index_item` (again, compare with `edit_item` in the list above):

```
item GET    /items/:id/index(.:format) items#show {:with=>"index"}
     GET    /items/:id(.:format)       items#show
```

However, had I used something other than `index`, such as `show_index`, then it would work as expected:

```
get 'show_index' => 'items#show', with: 'index', on: :member
```

produces

```
show_index_item GET    /items/:id/show_index(.:format) items#show {:with=>"index"}
```

So there is a difference in behaviour when the route is called `index`. I expect this is because the implied `resources` routes use that name, although I don't think they use it in a way that would clash. It looks to me like I should be able to add a new `index` route which would become `index_item` (similar to the exisitng `edit_item` and in contrast to the existing `item_index`).

I know I can work around the problem, as I have demonstrated, by using a different name. But `index` reads better than `show_index`.

So my question asks **is it possible to specify a resource route with `index` that is keyed off `:id`** ?
`

Comment: try `get 'index' => 'items#show', with: 'index', on: :member, as: 'item_index'`

Comment: One of Rails' key concepts is "Convention over configuration." Your plan is to use one of the seven Rails default actions as a route name  In that decision, you're using configuration over convention, and that's a Rails anti-pattern. Is it possible to make it work? Sure, but it's not code you would want to show as an example of your work on a Rails app.

Comment: But this doesn't change the seven rails default actions. It adds another action which fits in with the seven default actions. It just so happens that the logical name for that action is `index` but it doesn't affect the default actions in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set specific url use `as` key word, so try something like:

```
get 'index' => 'items#show', with: 'index', on: :member, as: 'item_index'
```

or one of course on your wish.

Comment: Using `item_index` results in methods prefixed with `item_index_item`, but using `index` gives the expected result of `index_item`.